# Доступ по API для разработчиков в систему MoySklad

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Коллеги. Прошу помощи. Как включить доступ по апи для разработчика, но сделать так чтобы он не мог ничего сделать в веб интерфейсе. Особенно смотреть прибыли остатки и продаже. Как вариант который я предполагаю работоспособным - это в настройках сотрудника включить только доступ по API а все остальное сделать выключеным

Answer (score 1):

Галочка в настройках сотрудника нужна для предоставления доступа сотруднику к Мой Склад через приложения, отличные от основного интерфейса(приложение для кассы, бэк офис для ios и т.п.).
Так же, если разрабатываемый скрипт должен будет работать с чем то, к чему Вы доступ ему закроете, то он не сможет ни чего тестировать, т.к. Мой Склад не будет ему предоставлять запрашиваемые данные.
Если действительно есть необходимость утаить от разработчика Ваши данные по продажам, то лучшим вариантом будет создание стендовой конфигурации Мой Склад, в виде регистрации нового аккаунта на тестовом периоде лицензии для отладки скрипта. 
В дальнейшем, после тестирования и отладки, Вам будет достаточно в готовый скрипт вставить логин и пароль от Вашей учетной записи Мой Склад. Желательно именно ту, что с админ правами.
И еще уточнение. Если при разработке потребуется установить Веб-хук, то к сожалению единственный способ сделать это - передать разработчику логин и пароль от учетной записи хозяина аккаунта Мой Склад.

Comment: Даже, если бы была возможность закрыть доступ к веб-версии, то через АПИ можно получить большую часть данных. Используйте тестовый стенд, да.